# an unwanted empty line is printed. can someone help me to remove it?

Tags: c++

as visible in the output images attached, an unwanted line is printed. if someone can help me with removing it, I would be really thankful:)
thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int a, b;
    
    cin>>a;
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    
    for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
        if (i==1) {
            cout<<"one"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==2) {
            cout<<"two"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==3) {
            cout<<"three"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==4) {
            cout<<"four"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==5) {
            cout<<"five"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==6) {
            cout<<"six"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==7) {
            cout<<"seven"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==8) {
            cout<<"eight"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else if (i==9) {
            cout<<"nine"<<endl;
            
        }
        
        else {
            if (i%2==0) {
                cout<<"even"<<endl;
            } else {
                cout<<"odd"<<endl;
            }
            
        }
    } 
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW1rp.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRViJ.png)

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYuNZ.png)

actually this is a question on Hackerrank. I checked for the solution online, it exactly matches with my code. so I am not able to find the error in this code.

Comment: please don't post images of text

Comment: @devm Did you try any of my suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You explicitly print the empty line between reading `a` and `b`:

```cpp
    cin>>a;
    cout<<endl;  // here
    cin>>b;
```

Just remove that line:

```cpp
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
```

or better, read both and make sure that reading succeeded before continuing:

```
    if(not (std::cin >> a >> b)) return 1;
```